# Remove datasource binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a page like this

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!--
        這個頁面顯示的群組項目集合，繫結到完整項目
        清單的子集，因為群組中的項目無法虛擬化
    -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Groups}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="TopItems"
        d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>

    <!-- TODO: 如果已在 App.xaml 中宣告金鑰 AppName，則刪除這一行 -->
    <x:String x:Key="AppName">我的應用程式</x:String>
</Page.Resources>

    <local:MyGridView            
        Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Padding="116,0,40,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"                    
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        IsSwipeEnabled="True"
        IsRightTapEnabled="False"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"                    
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard180x240ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionChanged="itemGridView_SelectionChanged_1"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

        <local:MyGridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </local:MyGridView.ItemsPanel>
        <local:MyGridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6" >
                            <Button AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title" Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <!--<VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>-->
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="8" ItemWidth="180" ItemHeight="240" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </local:MyGridView.GroupStyle>
    </local:MyGridView>
```

and when i try to remove selected items in below code:

```
private void Delete()
{
    var group = SampleDataSource.GetGroup("myGroup");
    foreach (SampleDataItem item in itemGridView.SelectedItems)
    {
        group.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

i get error in App.gi.cs file here

```
 #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)     
                global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
 #endif
```

e.Message is shown:

"Multiple animations in the same containing Storyboard cannot target the same property on a single element."    string

So how can i remove selected items ?

Thanks your help.

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted to know why its happening but I don't find anything. But I have a solution:

```
private void Delete()
{
    IList<SampleDataItem> selectedItems = new List<SampleDataItem>();
    foreach (SampleDataItem item in itemGridView.SelectedItems)
    {
        selectedItems.Add(item);
    }
    var group = SampleDataSource.GetGroup("myGroup");
    foreach (SampleDataItem item in selectedItems)
    {
        group.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

If you discovered "why" please let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a compiler in front of me but have you tried something like:

```
group.Items.RemoveAll(itemGridView.SelectedItems);
```

instead of your foreach loop. You might find a cross dependency between SelectedItems and group is the issue (so do the remove outside the loop).

Comment: Hi, i don't see RemoveAll Method,
Only Remove(), RemoveAt()

Comment: Actully, this is my second page. I do the same thing in my first page, 
and it is work. So it confused me, why i can't do this in second page?